# Deploy react app on gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I'm tryin to host my react app on github pages but after i done it gives me blank site: https://whomean.github.io/app/

I do it along this instruction: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages

Any ideas where is the problem?

Comment: You should wait about 5 minutes then hit Ctrl+F5 to reload page without cache... You deploy need some time...

Answer (score 0):

I followed the gh-pages instructions in the create-react-app readme.md and it worked perfectly

Comment: did you change repo settings to push to `gh-pages-branch` (step 4)?